# SlideAnimation is not working properly in android?

Tags: android, animation, slide

I developed slideAnimation for my Activity,But its not working some times means the animation stared and ended and again started. i.e., the animation is done but its comes back to the previous state again. But some times its working perfectly.

[image]
 i am using the following code :

```
class ClickListener implements OnClickListener {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
//         live=false;
//         setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT);
//         player.suspend();
//         player.resume();          

//            System.out.println("onClick " + new Date());
            SlideAnimationThenCallLayout me = SlideAnimationThenCallLayout.this;

            int w = app.getMeasuredWidth();
            int h = app.getMeasuredHeight();
            int left = (int) (app.getMeasuredWidth() * 0.65);

            if (!menuOut) {
             menucheck=true;
//             if(responed.equals("zero")){}
//             else
//             layout.setClickable(false);

                // anim = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(context, R.anim.push_right_out_80);
                anim = new TranslateAnimation(0, left, 0, 0);
                menu.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                animParams.init(left, 0, left + w, h);
            } else {
             menucheck=false;
//             layout.setClickable(true);

                // anim = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(context, R.anim.push_left_in_80);
                anim = new TranslateAnimation(0, -left, 0, 0);
                animParams.init(0, 0, w, h);
            }

            anim.setDuration(500);
            anim.setAnimationListener(me);
            //Tell the animation to stay as it ended (we are going to set the app.layout first than remove this property)
            anim.setFillAfter(true);

            // Only use fillEnabled and fillAfter if we don't call layout ourselves.
            // We need to do the layout ourselves and not use fillEnabled and fillAfter because when the anim is finished
            // although the View appears to have moved, it is actually just a drawing effect and the View hasn't moved.
            // Therefore clicking on the screen where the button appears does not work, but clicking where the View *was* does
            // work.
            // anim.setFillEnabled(true);
            // anim.setFillAfter(true);

            app.startAnimation(anim);
        }
    }
    public void onAnimationEnd(Animation animation) {
        System.out.println("onAnimationEnd");
        ViewUtils.printView("menu", menu);
        Log.e("this is","onAnimaition end");
        ViewUtils.printView("app", app);
        menuOut = !menuOut;
        if (!menuOut) {
            menu.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        }
        layoutApp(menuOut);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You are likely doing something differently before when it doesn't work, you question isn't very detailed so I recomend you use your app and try to find a pattern that forms when the menu doesnt work and if you see that a certain thing is causing it not to work find that section in your code and edit it.

Comment: Thank you for response.,But i can't understand what u said could you please give clear explonation...

Comment: @Santosh Likely what is happening is you go to a page in the app or click something which may initialize or do something to a variable in your code causing the animation not to work. For Example if when you instantly open the app the animation works perfectly then once you have done a few things in the app and gone to a few different pages try to use the animation again and it doesnt work, that means when you go to a different page or do something that it is causing the animation to change

Comment: i have only one activity in my application and using using slide animation but its not working

Comment: @Santosh could you add that entire activity to your question